# Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0

Tags: java, android, github, android-viewpager, jitpack

This is in relation to antonyt's InfiniteViewPager: https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

I have no idea why this isn't building in Android Studio and the issues page on his repo is not very helpful at the moment.

I added the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0'
    }
```

And I have the following repositories connected:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: any error? you could see it with running ./gradlew -stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to be careful about spelling. Since a lot of people seem to be stuck with this I'd recommend leaving this up. The dependency is CAPS-sensitive:

```
compile 'com.github.antonyt:InfiniteViewPager:v1.0.0'
```